# How to fix "Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'transactions_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'account'"

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to create a foreign key and keep getting this message:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
>   index for constraint 'transactions_ibfk_1' in the referenced table
>   'account'

Very new to programming and sql in general so sorry if this is simple.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bank;
USE bank;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account
(
account_id int primary key auto_increment,
balance double,
type varchar(30),
date_opened datetime,
status varchar(30)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions
(
transaction_id int primary key auto_increment,
date_time datetime,
amount double,
remaining_balance double,
account_id int
);
alter table transactions
add foreign key(account_id)
references account(account_id)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;
```

Comment: index  the field 'account_id' in table transactions and try

Comment: Which version of mysql are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I think the name of the foreign key should be different.
for the last part i.e creation of foreign key, try the below snippet

```
ALTER TABLE `bank`.`transactions` 
ADD INDEX `fk_account_id_idx` (`account_id` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `bank`.`transactions` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_account_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`)
  REFERENCES `bank`.`account` (`account_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```